# openflow rule with multiple action ports

Tags: openflow, opendaylight

I am a little bit confused when interpreting the action part for the following rule

**cookie=0x2b000000000000a5, duration=528.939s, table=0, n_packets=176, n_bytes=33116, idle_age=0, priority=2,in_port=1 actions=output:4,output:2**

we have multiple action ports in a certain order, when checking the "**restconf/operational/opendaylight-inventory:nodes/**"  in ODL controller we have different order for each port

```
                "action": [
                          { "order": 0,"output-action": {
                                       "max-length": 65535,
                                        "output-node-connector": "2" }
                          {"order": 1, "output-action": {
                                        "max-length": 65535,
                                        "output-node-connector": "4" }
                                                }
```

I am not sure how the packets hitting such entry will be forwarded, are they replicated and send over both? are they load balanced over all ports?

what does the max-length refer to?

Is there any documentation explaining all fields in detail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems, this is a group-table flow.

You can use group table functionality to support multiports in action part. You can read [Openflow 1.3 spec documentation](https://www.opennetworking.org/images/stories/downloads/sdn-resources/onf-specifications/openflow/openflow-spec-v1.3.0.pdf) for details. (Part. 5.6, 5.6.1)

For max length, again from the same document (Part A.2.5):

> An Output action uses the following structure and fields:
>
> Action structure for OFPAT_OUTPUT, which sends packets out 'port'. When the
> 'port' is the OFPP_CONTROLLER, 'max_len' indicates the max number of
> bytes to send. A 'max_len' of zero means no bytes of the packet should
> be sent. A 'max_len' of OFPCML_NO_BUFFER means that the packet is not
> buffered and the complete packet is to be sent to the controller.

Comment: I checked the documentation, but still not clear how the packets are treated. the "action bucket" is not clearly interpreted :(                                I got the rule by initiating the "ovs-ofctl dump-flows" on my mininet openflow switch. these rules were automatically created by the ODL controller.